# F# Pattern matching and functions

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I tried to implement the fibonacci sequence in F# using pattern matching like this:

```
let fibonacci m=
    let rec fib = function
        | (0, _, z) -> z
        | (n, y, z) -> fib (n-1) z (y+z)
    fib m 0 1
```

Here I expect the first argument to fib to keep track of how far along in the sequence we are, and the next two arguments to be successive terms in the sequence.

However, I'm getting a compile-time error on `fib (n-1) z (y+z)`:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a -> 'b -> 'c    
but given a
    'c    
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''b -> 'c -> 'a'
```

I tried specifying types like so:

```
let fibonacci m=
    let rec fib = function
        | (0, _, z:int) -> z
        | (n:int, y:int, z:int) -> fib (n-1) z (y+z)
    fib m 0 1
```

And then I get a different compile error on `fib (n-1)`:

```
This value is not a function and cannot be applied
```

I'm still trying to get my head around functional programming. I think the problem might be my lack of understanding in what the first pattern actually means. I want it mean that when the position argument is zero, it returns the second argument term.

Could someone help me with this problem which is obviously due to some basic misunderstanding on my part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're calling the function with curried arguments when in fact is defined as expecting tupled arguments:

```
let fibonacci m =
    let rec fib = function
        | (0, _, z) -> z
        | (n, y, z) -> fib (n-1, z, y+z)
    fib (m, 0, 1)
```

This is because you are using `function` which pattern match a single argument, in your case against a tuple. The alternative is to use `match`

```
let fibonacci m =
    let rec fib a b c = 
        match (a, b, c) with
        | (0, _, z) -> z
        | (n, y, z) -> fib (n-1) z (y+z)
    fib m 0 1
```

You can think of `function` as a shorthand for a single argument function followed by a `match` over that argument.

Comment: Right that makes sense, I guess you can only really pattern match on a single entity, not a list of arguments

Comment: Yes, you can. See the update with the example with the match ... with.